# Convert Pandas column of numpy arrays to python list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to a convert a pandas column of numpy arrays to lists?

Pandas dataframe construction

```
A = np.random.randint(0,15000000,65000)                                      
B = [np.random.randint(0,15000000,k) for k in np.random.randint(2,101,100)]

A32 = A.astype(np.int32)

from itertools import chain

sizes = np.fromiter(chain((0,),map(len,B)),np.int32,len(B)+1)
boundaries = sizes.cumsum()

# force int32
B_all = np.empty(boundaries[-1],np.int32)
B32 = np.split(B_all, boundaries[1:-1])
df = pd.DataFrame([A32, B32]).T
```

Attempt to convert 2nd column to list

```
df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: x.tolist() )
```

Resulting error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-6d36b7b9c250> in <module>()
----> 1 df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: x.tolist() )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-35-6d36b7b9c250> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: x.tolist() )

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

Comment: Have you tried https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I am going to assume `A32` is a typo (since it doesn't exist), and that you meant to use `A`.

`A` has a length of 65000, `B32` has a length of 100. Column `1` of your dataframe is getting extended to 65000 with `NaN`s (a float value), which obviously has no `tolist` method. That is why you are getting this error. To fix this, you can either use only the first 100 elements of `A`, that is `A[:100]`, or you can just make `B32` as long as `A`.

Comment: I forgot a line where I convert it to int32, I added it in.